# Adding oribit circle and label in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am developing a small planetary system, in which I have added some rotating and revolving planets around a pivot star.

This is the code which does the above:

```
  var mercury = createMesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(5.0, 10, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2), "mercury.png");
        mercury.position.x = 4;
        scene.add(mercury);
            var speed = 100;
            var distance = 2;
            mercury.position.x = Math.sin(step * speed) * distance*5;
            mercury.position.y = Math.cos(step * speed) * distance;
            mercury.position.z = Math.cos(step * speed) * distance * 5;
```

Now I want to add a circle for each moving planet that will show the trajectory of the satellite around the pivot planet and add a label on the top of the planet, like a "mercury" label on the aforesaid planet, in my case. How would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Orbit Path

You can render a circle a couple of different ways. You can use [Three.js lines](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Objects/Line), like in [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_lines).

Or you could render [a torus](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Extras.Geometries/TorusGeometry) to mark the path.

### Text

You can create more geometry as a text, [as in this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_text).

Or you can use sprites with text, talked about in [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514274/three-js-2d-text-sprite-labels).

### Pattern

Note that you're hard-coding your planet again, like in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947341/adding-number-of-cubes-in-three-js/). I recommend that you DRY out your code by creating a function that builds the three.js objects for you. Something with a signature such as:

```
function createPlanetParent(planetName,planetDiameter,planetRadius,...) {...}
```

That way you can separate out your data (planet information) from view code (three.js geometry and pivots).